# Iterating over a map in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have an map returned from the server, in java its

```
private Map<Case, Integer> files;
```

So its a Case object is the keyt and the value int he map is an integer of how many of those cases occured.

in react i get the following response from the backend:

```
{user: "test", files: {{name='xcase', id=1}: 2, {name='ycase', id=2}: 1}}, totalNumberOfCases: 3}
```

Im not sure how i can iterate this, to print out the name,id and integer

I have tried map iteration, this.state.files.map.... but that doesnt seem to work.

So im trying to iterate over and put the file map of key values in a table.

Comment: that object doesnt look valid. What is the serialized response in the rect component?

Comment: this is not valid javascript, are you sure that is the correct response?

Comment: It's not valid Javascript, but it is valid JSON. Javascript object keys are strings, so when you have a complex object as a hash/map key like that it gets translated to a string. So your object key ends up literally the string ``"{name='case', id=1}"``.

Comment: @HassaanTauqir  - updated the json tot he full response the react get call has

Comment: Can you use postman to get a json response from the api and post that response here, it is hard to understand it in the current condition because it is at the moment still not valid json or object. I am guessing the file is a complete string but you will have to verify that. Also, shouldn't the java code be responsible for converting this to appropriate json and sending it over to you instead of you handling it on the frontend?

Comment: If you are asking about iterating over the values in ``files`` (i.e., 1, 2...), something like ``Object.values().map`` will work fine. If you are asking about iterating over the individual properties in the keys, they're no longer actual objects when they get to Javascript; they're just a string representation.

Comment: @rmlockerd  you are right... i have asked to get the backend end response chnaged

Comment: @HassaanTauqir thank you, yes the backend needs to send me a better constructed JSON. So now i have asked for a list of objects with the count as part of it.

Answer (score 0):

Json needs to be amended. A better approach is to have a list of objects.